# Why doesn't this star-rating javascript/CSS work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying for quite a while to get this 5 star-rating control from Nick Salloum to work:
http://callmenick.com/post/five-star-rating-component-with-javascript-css

Here is my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/n6qzkpcy/2/

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong that it isn't showing any stars?

```
// target element
var el = document.querySelector('#el');

// current rating, or initial rating
var currentRating = 0;

// max rating, i.e. number of stars you want
var maxRating= 5;

// callback to run after setting the rating
var callback = function(rating) { alert(rating); };

// rating instance
var myRating = rating(el, currentRating, maxRating, callback);
```

Comment: Did you check the console of your fiddle?
It says, "Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/callmenick/five-star-rating/master/js/src/rating.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

The GitHub link that you used doesn't have the executable mimetype and thus fiddle.com isn't allowed to execute it

Comment: there are two errors in the console.. firstly, you cant load the `svg` star from github, as it has `text/plain` encoding, you will need to download it and host it elsewhere, also, the `rating.js` file you're including, doesnt expose the `rating` function globally, so you're calling an undefined function

Comment: I would suggest, downloading the library and checking it on your local. I did and it just works perfectly fine

Comment: @Sanchit That's what I did and have been trying to get it going for over an hour. Can you let me see your HTML page source for it? Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: OK. I've removed all external references in that JSFiddle and now have: https://jsfiddle.net/n6qzkpcy/6/ .  It still isn't showing any stars -- if anyone can fork that so that it works that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have answered with my HTML and that is working fine. Please include all the js and css which are required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Five Star Rating</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/rating.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<ul class="c-rating" id="el">

</ul>

<script src="js/dist/rating.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var el = document.querySelector('#el');

    // current rating, or initial rating
    var currentRating = 1;

    // max rating, i.e. number of stars you want
    var maxRating= 5;

    // callback to run after setting the rating
    var callback = function(rating) { alert(rating); };

    // rating instance
    var myRating = rating(el, currentRating, maxRating, callback);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please use the above HTML page and place the required resources as downloaded from git. You would see the result.

Comment: Eureka - thank you. I guess the orginal <div id="el"></div> needed to be replaced by your <ul class="c-rating" id="el"></ul>

Comment: Yes. The element that needs the rating should have 'el' as id for the JS to work AND 'c_rating' for the CSS to work